# Is it possible to install jboss esb into jboss as 7?

Tags: jboss

We are planning to migrate out applications to JBoss AS 7, but we use JBoss ESB. Is it possible to run JBoss ESB with JBoss AS 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to run Boss ESB with JBoss AS 5 and 6 but not with 7th version. So if you want to migrate, use JBoss AS 5 or 6 instead (look the accepted answer here: https://community.jboss.org/thread/220888?_sscc=t).

Comment: Humm... Lets wait hoping for the best. Maybe Red Hat do this after EAP 6.1 is released.